# Discrete Probability: You are given a string of length n, in which each character is a uniformly random element of {a.b.c}

Tags: probability, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, random-variables

> **Question:** A string $s_1s_2\ldots s_n$ is a palindrome if $s_1s_2\ldots s_{n-1}s_n = s_ns_{n-1}...s_2s_1 $; i.e reading the string from left to right gives the same result as reading the string from right to left.
>
> Let $n \ge 3$, be an odd integer. You are given a string of length $n$, in which each character is a uniformly random element of $\{a,b,c\}$. The characters are independent of each other. What is the probability that this bitstring is a palindrome?

**Answer: $(1/3)^{(n-1)/2}$**

---

**Attempt:**

I took $n=3$, with a string `aba` to make a palindrome. For the first character `a`, I have 3 options and must choose one of them. For `b`, I have 2 options and I must choose 1. And for `a`, I have 1 option and must pick 1 to make it a palindrome.

I used the binomial for all three cases and got 
$$
Pr(A_1) = \binom{3}{1}*(1/3)^1*(1 - 1/3)^2 = 4/9\\
Pr(A_2) = \binom{2}{1}*(1/2)^1*(1-1/2)^1 = 1/2\\
Pr(A_3) = \binom{1}{1}*(1/2)^1*(1/2)^0 = 1/2
$$
Finally,
$$Pr(A) = (4/9)*(1/2)*(1/2) = 1/9 = (1/3)^{(n+1)/2}
\quad {\text for } \quad n=3$$

But according to the answer, it should be $Pr(A) = 1/3$. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: For a string of length $3$ the only condition needed for it to be a palindrome is for the first character to equal the last.

Comment: @lulu does my binomial method not apply to this case? I got my final answer to be 1/9 but the answer is 1/3. Do I have to multiply my final answer by 3 to get it right?

Comment: I don't understand your method.  I don't know what the $A_i$ are.  I don't understand what "For the first character a, I have 3 options and must choose one of them." means.

Comment: @lulu I chose "aba" as an example of a palindrome with length 3. So, as you said I only need the first and third characters to be equal. I just attempted to find the individual probabilities of each character slot using the binomial and multiplied them to get the overall probability. Now, looking back what I did doesn't seem right. I'm just wondering if a binomial method can apply to this question

Comment: I don't understand the point of choosing an explicit example.  The general form is $XYX$...the condition that the first and third entries coincide has probability $\frac 13$.

Comment: @lulu if I had to determine the probability with n=4, how would I go about it? Shouldn't it then follow the generic XYYX form? Would it just be 1/4 for the 1st and 4th to coincide for this case just like the previous n=3 case?

Comment: The problem specified that $n$ was odd.  But...there is a $\frac 13$ chance that the third entry matches the second, and a $\frac 13$ chance that the fourth entry matches the first, so $\frac 13\times \frac 13=\frac 19$.

Comment: There's a formula for even $n$ as well, you can try to discover it.

Comment: Oh I forgot it's supposed to be for odd, because the formula doesn't give 1/9 for n=4 but it does give that for n=5, so XYYYX, in this case there is a 1/3 chance that X1=X5 and a 1/3 chance that Y2=Y3=Y4?

Comment: Please be more careful.  You do not need the three middle ones to match.  The pattern $XYZYX$ is a palindrome.

Comment: Oh that is true, but isn't XYYYX still a palindrome?

Comment: Yes, but it is not the general pattern.  Writing $XYZYX$ does not preclude $Z=Y$.

Comment: So, should XYZYX and XYYYX give the same result for n=5. For XYZYX it is simply X1=X5 is 1/3 and Y2=Y4 is 1/3. So, 1/3*1/3 = 1/9. But for XYYYX, X1=X5 is 1/3 and Y2=Y3=Y5 is 1/27. 1/27*1/3 = 1/81. According to this, the answers are different.

Comment: Of course they don't give the same answer.  Why should they?  They are different patterns.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is, out of $n = 2k+1$ positions, you pick the first $k+1$, then fix the last $k$ to be exactly like the first $k$ in reverse order. The number of such strings is $3^{k+1}$. The total number of string in question is $3^n=3^{2k+1}$, so the probability would be
$$
3^{k+1}/3^n = 3^{k+1-(2k+1)} = 3^{-k}.
$$